# setTimeout в неактивной вкладке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую вот такой таймер с автокоррекцией, костылями сделал из него обратный таймер (вывод в консоль идет в обратном порядке)

```js
function toFixed(num, fixed) {
       return (Math.floor(num * Math.pow(10, fixed)) / Math.pow(10, fixed)).toFixed(fixed);
    }
 
    function timerback(time_f) {
  
        var timeout;
        var speed = 50;
        var finish = (time_f * 1000) / 50;
        var counter = 0;
        var start = new Date().getTime();

        function instance() {
            var real = (counter * speed);
            var ideal = (new Date().getTime() - start);

            counter++;
            var diff = (ideal - real);

            console.log(toFixed(time_f - toFixed(ideal / 1000.0, 2),2));

            if (counter - 1 != finish) {

                timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    instance();
                }, Math.max((speed - diff),0));

            } else {  
    
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                console.log('TIMER FINISH');
            }
        };

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            instance();
        }, speed);
    }
    
    timerback(5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вызов этой функции происходит вот так timerback(5) 
5 - секунд будет ждать таймер.
Функция вызывается по суте бесконечно с периодом в 10-15 секунд (такая концепция проекта)

Но если вкладка в браузере не активна, то происходит необъяснимые вещи, то таймер останавливается то считает больше чем надо то меньше.

Вот эта библиотека ничем не помогает https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer

Как сделать чтобы таймер работал одинаково хорошо вне зависимости от активности вкладки в браузере ?

Из библиотек использую

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js
jquery.easing.1.3.js
socket.io.js
accounting.min.js
tinysort.min.js
materialize.min.js
jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: Какая исходная задача решается?

Comment: Просто клиенту с периодом в 10-15 секунд надо показать таймер обратного отсчета допустим 20ти секунд. 1) Клиент зашел на сайт 2) Запустился таймер обратного отсчета 20 секунд 3) Таймер завершен 4) Выполняются какие-то действия примерно в течении 10-15 секунд 5) Запустился таймер обратного отчета 20 секунд .......

Comment: Зачем вы придумываете велосипед? Тамер задаётся аналогично функцией `window.setInterval` погуглите её почитайте описание.

Comment: Велосипед я изобрел, потому что setInterval выполняется неверно, он не учитывает время которое уходит на выполнение callback функции. Статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/212889/

Comment: Тогда синхнонизируйтесь в таймере с  ф-цией `new Date()` на интервал пол-секунды-секунда. А время выполнения и правда сложно спрогнозировать.

Comment: Да и какая разница по большому счету setInterval или setTimeout, обе эти функции работают не корректно в неактивной вкладке

Comment: Если вы не заметили в приведенном мной коде выше и так реализован механизм автокоррекции, неточность сведена к 2м миллисекундам.

Comment: Вопрос немного запутан, давайте его перефразируем более понятно. Вы хотите некую ф-цию timer которая "стабильно" вызывается раз в секунду (или раз в сколько)?

Comment: Да функция работает прекрасно и так, просто если вкладка в браузере будет не активна то такие браузеры как Crome/Mofzilla и так далее автоматически выставляют минимальный интервал для setTimeout и setInterval на 1000 мс (1 секунда), а у меня данный таймер внутри себя работает с задержкой 50 мс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таймеры в JS работают крайне нестабильно. Я бы рекомендовал Вам запоминать начальное время, а потом вызвать `setInterval` с небольшим дискретом. И в ней проверять прошло ли с момента старта достаточно времени

С учетом уточнения

> Пользователь должен видеть обратный отсчет 20-ти секунд включая сотые доли секунды например 19.29 (19 секунд | 290 миллисекунд)

```js
var startTime = new Date();
setInterval(function() {
  var curTime = new Date();
  var delta = curTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
  if (delta > 20000) {
    console.log('20 seconds expired');
    startTime = new Date();
  } else
    document.getElementById('time').innerText = (20 - delta / 1000).toFixed(2);
}, 50);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Comment: Я не понимаю как я не так объясняю, код таймера и подходы могут быть любыми, но если вкладка в браузере НЕ АКТИВНА, то сам браузер устанавливает минимальный интервал в 1000 мс, а мой таймер должен работать каждые 50 мс внутри себя чтобы сообщать пользователю, сколько осталось до конца таймера

Comment: @LorDo 1. Кому он будет сообщать, если вкладка неактивна? 2. Какой пользователь в состоянии увидеть картинку, изменяющуюся каждые 50 мс?

Comment: 1) Никому, воздуху. 2) Я добавил выполнении кода в шапке вопроса, там в консоль будут выводится текущие значение. Так вот если вывод не в консоль а в любой div элемент. Вы не различите цифр ?

Comment: Вы можете увидеть проблему таким образом, нажмите выполнение кода в шапке вопроса и он отработает отлично 5 секунд, затем нажмите кнопку выполнения кода в шапке и переключитесь на другую вкладку в браузере и подождите 5-6 секунд для верности, вернувшись вы обнаруживаете отрицательные значения.

Comment: @LorDo Каждые 50 мс? Нет.

Comment: Мы не о том разговариваем. Допустим увеличить значение до 100 мс. Вы же увидите изменение десятых секунды, верно ? 5.90 5.80 5.70. Если нет, можете считать что мой проект ориентирован на особо зорких юзеров.

Comment: @LorDo Вот именно, что не о том. Я первым вопросом попросил уточнить задачу. Вы сказали, раз в 20 секунд выполнять действия. Теперь Вы говорите о каких-то миллисекундах. Сформулируйте задачу

Comment: Пользователь должен видеть обратный отсчет 20-ти секунд включая сотые доли секунды например 19.29 (19 секунд | 290 миллисекунд) https://jsfiddle.net/06hhqtkd/

Comment: Я с вами согласен что сотые секунды не различимы, окей мы можем поднять интервал таймера до 100 мс, а сотые секунды сделать рандом от 0 до 9, человек вряд ли увидит подвод, но что сделать с десятыми секундами, они очень даже различимы 19.9 19.8 19.7

Comment: @LorDo модифицировал ответ

Comment: Тестирую ваш вариант, пока что возник вопрос форматирования, секунды должны быть с ведущими нулями, т.е. должно быть не 1.22 а 01.22, и также мили секунды должны быть 2 символа в длину, например не 15.2 а 15.20 | не 13 а 13.00

Comment: Форматирование решил с помощью функции toFixed из шапки вопроса и небольшого костылька ("0"+toFixed(20 - delta / 1000, 2)).substr(-5)